# Android : Seeking for optimized solution to get those contacts who have installed my app

Tags: android

I have 50K+ user in my server, Now i have to show those contacts who have installed my app in their device.

For that i am uploading contact list from user's device then compering with my all server contacts so its a big process.

Is there any other optimized solution for that ? 
Please suggest.

Comment: Let me know if you achive some useful solution to this problem @Jahangir Kabir